# Is it possible to debug Perl that contains XS sections to see the program flow?

Tags: c++, perl, debugging, perl-xs

I have a project written in Perl with XS components written in C++. I am debugging with command like

```
perl -d perl_file.pl
```

How I can use the debugger to jump from Perl into those C++ files?

Comment: Do you mean you are making calls from the Perl code into the C++ code? How?

Comment: I mean the Perl scripts call C++ files. But I don't know how to keep debugging and get access to those C++ files.

Comment: You can call an executable, but how do you call (run/invoke) a source file?

Comment: @legends2k from a source file.

Comment: Please answer the question and explain how you are calling the C++ code from within Perl. Example code is always helpful

Comment: @borodin I am sorry to say that I got this project from someone else, unable to contact the guy. This project contains Perl and C++ files (c++ is stored in XS folder). As far as I know now, I run debugging start from perl_file.pl, and keep jumping into other Perl files. I am looking for how to call C++ file from the debugging process. There is an important calculation in C++ file which I want to know, but I am unable to call those C++ file.

Comment: Ah so it's XS code. That makes a lot more sense. The Perl debugger won't let you step through the C code, and the best way to diagnose problems there is to add `printf` statements to trace the values during the execution

Comment: To debug C++ code, you need a C++ debugger, e.g. `gdb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use GNU Project Debugger.

```
gdb /usr/bin/perl
    r perl_file.pl
```

See perlhacktips:

- [Using gdb to look at specific parts of a program](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhacktips.html#Using-gdb-to-look-at-specific-parts-of-a-program)
- [Using gdb to look at what the parser/lexer are doing](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhacktips.html#Using-gdb-to-look-at-what-the-parser%2Flexer-are-doing)

Also see:

- [Get a stack trace from your running perl](http://use.perl.org/use.perl.org/_jjore/journal/39319.html)
- [App::Stacktrace](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::Stacktrace)

Comment: See also [How do I trace through an XS .so file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50643536/2173773)